# Central Feature Tool Key Error u'M'

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap

I was trying to execute two tools (Mean Center Tool and Central Feature) when suddenly it gave me a error that I couldn't find the resolution too no matter what I tryed. The code is here (along with a link to the image of the error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts\CentralFeature.py",       line 301, in <module>
 setupCentralFeature()
 File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts\CentralFeature.py",   line 47, in setupCentralFeature
  ssdo = SSDO.SSDataObject(inputFC, templateFC = outputFC)
 File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSDataObject.py", line 288, in __init__
 self.distanceInfo = UTILS.DistanceInfo(self.spatialRef)
 File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSUtilities.py", line 2135, in __init__
 self.setInfo()
 File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSUtilities.py", line 2155, in setInfo
 info = distanceUnitInfo[self.name]
 KeyError: u'M'

 Failed to execute (CentralFeature).
 Failed at Thu Jul 31 16:10:13 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.97 seconds)
```

Can someone explain what seems to be the problem here ? 
If it's of good use, I am doing this on a point feature

[image: feature info]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

The SSDataObject allows for a wide array of spatial references, with a lot of linear/angular units, but it is sometimes possible for a spatial reference to have a linear/angular unit that is not in the known list.  That is what is happening here: `'M'` is not a known linear unit.

The quick solution is to project your data to a known spatial reference.  You could also register your linear unit (assuming `'M'` means METERS or something else you are aware of) by placing it in the `distanceInfo` dictionary before you call the `SSDataObject`.  It is located at the very end of the `SSUtilities.py` file in the `%ARCHOME%/ArcToolbox/Scripts` directory. There you will see the exhaustive list of linear/angular units that are allowed in the Spatial Stats Tools. You will need to know how your unit converts to Meters for linear or Decimal Degrees for angular.  An entry in the `distanceInfo` dict looks like:

```
"NAME IN SPATIAL REF": ("Pretty Print / Plural Name",
                        conversion factor to either METERS or Dec Degree)
```

For example, before calling your tool (assuming `M` is indeed meters):

```
import SSUtilities
SSUtilities.distanceUnitInfo[u'M'] = (u'Meters (Custom)', 1.0)
```